# Browser (Edge, Chrome) sends Connection: Close but says it sent Connection: Keep-Alive

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, firefox, microsoft-edge

When making an HTTP request in Microsoft Edge or Google Chrome, in the Request Headers in the Network section of the developer tools, it says that it sent `keep-alive` as value for the `Connection` header:
[image]

But when I receive and print the request on the server side I can see that it actually sent `close`.

To see what I receive on the server side I ran this Python script:

```
import socket
import sys
 
HOST = 'localhost' 
PORT = 8282
   
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  
try:
    soc.bind((HOST, PORT))
      
except socket.error as message:
     
    print('Bind failed. Error Code : '
          + str(message[0]) + ' Message '
          + message[1])
    sys.exit()
  
soc.listen(9)
  
conn, address = soc.accept()
print('Connected with ' + address[0] + ':'
      + str(address[1]))

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if data:
        print(data)
    else:
        break
```

which gave me the following console output:

```
Connected with 127.0.0.1:54596
b'POST /auth/create HTTP/1.1\r\ncookie: XXXXX\r\naccept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\naccept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nreferer: http://localhost:3000/auth/login\r\nsec-fetch-dest: empty\r\nsec-fetch-mode: cors\r\nsec-fetch-site: same-origin\r\norigin: http://localhost:3000\r\nsec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"\r\nuser-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/119.0.0.0\r\nsec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0\r\ncontent-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\naccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nsec-ch-ua: "Microsoft Edge";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"\r\ncache-control: no-cache\r\npragma: no-cache\r\ncontent-length: 69\r\nconnection: close\r\nhost: localhost:8282\r\n\r\n{"email":"xxxxx","password":"xxxxx"}'
```

Is this a bug in Chromium? We want to keep the connection open for a while between requests for performance reasons. How do we achieve that?

Google Chrome version: 120.0.6099.71

Microsoft Edge version: 119.0.2151.97

**EDIT:** This is actually true in Mozilla Firefox as well:
[image]
Here it sent `close` just like Edge and Chrome.

Mozilla Firefox version: 114.0.1

**EDIT:** Here is what can be seen in Wireshark, as requested:
[image]

Comment: Interesting, perhaps you should raise it with the Chromium devs at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: so, you tested one browser - did you test in a different one?

Comment: I tested it in Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome.

Comment: The fact it's happening with both Chromium browsers *and* Firefox suggests it's not a bug in the browsers (which was always unlikely, but not impossible), but rather a misunderstanding, an observation error of some kind, or something about the Python code (which I guess you could call an observation error, but to me it's distinct).

Comment: I get the same header value in our actual backend. I wrote the script to be sure that the framework is not changing the value after it's received from the socket.

Comment: I'd stiff the actual network traffic (fiddler, Wireshark, etc.), just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for including the Wireshark info. This pretty much leaves observation error (though you've done multiple observations with multiple tools, so to me it's fairly unlikely to be observational error) or a misunderstanding of some kind. Hopefully someone can shed some light.